# stack overflows in xamarin mac

Tags: stack-overflow, unmanaged, xamarin.mac

I'm developing an mac app with Xamarin, im having stack overflows like this

```
Stack overflow in unmanaged: IP: 0x24a265, fault addr: 0xb049d4dc

Stack overflow in unmanaged: IP: 0x59b66, fault addr: 0xb049cd14

Stack overflow in unmanaged: IP: 0x24a265, fault addr: 0xb049d4dc

Stack overflow in unmanaged: IP: 0x59b66, fault addr: 0xb049cd14
```

im trying to figure out what "IP: 0x24a265" and "fault addr: 0xb049d4dc" means, please help to solve this I'm kind of stuck here.

Comment: I've run into this as well. Have you had any luck solving it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stack overflow in unmanaged: IP: 0x26eb76, fault addr: 0xbf808ffc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682308/stack-overflow-in-unmanaged-ip-0x26eb76-fault-addr-0xbf808ffc)